# Ways to select three-man teams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

**In a competition there are $18$ competitors. Answer the following:**

**A) During the first day they're competing in three-man teams (a total of $6$ teams). How many ways are there to select the teams?**

**B) If the main sponsor of the event demands that the four best-ranked players mustn't play in the same groups, how many ways can you then select the teams?**

I've tried the following:

A) There are $(18\cdot17\cdot16 + 15\cdot14\cdot13 + 12\cdot11\cdot10 +...+ 3\cdot2\cdot1)$ ways to select the teams, and if the order of the groups mattered we would just multiply that with $6!$

However, this gives me approximately $700000$ ways, whereas the correct number of ways according to the book is $190000000$

B) The four best players must each be in a different group. Therefore we "lock" their positions. $(1\cdot14\cdot13 + 1\cdot12\cdot11 + 1\cdot10\cdot9 + 1\cdot8\cdot7 + 6\cdot5\cdot4 + 3\cdot2\cdot1)$ gives us the ways to select the teams, and if the order of the groups matters, we multiply that by $6!.$

Once again, this value is far too small according to the book. Either my calculations are way off or the book is wrong.

Comment: Homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @TimSeguine Nope, not homework. My teacher and I couldn't get our heads around this today and I was simply curious to see how others would approach the problem.

Comment: You are leaving out the fact that the order of the players inside of each team doesn't matter. A team with Bob, Alice and Jane is the same as a team with Jane, Bob and Alice.

Comment: So I would take 18 over 3 plus 15 over 3....until 3 over 3? That would give me an even less value.

Comment: You are "zigging" where you should be "zagging", see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the binomial coefficient notation. $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is read "n choose k", the number of ways to choose $k$ items without replacement from a pool of $n$ distinct objects.

**A)** There are $\binom{18}{3}$ ways to choose the first team, $\binom{15}{3}$ ways to choose the second, etc. this gives $$\binom{18}{3}\binom{15}{3}\binom{12}{3}\binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{3}$$ ways to choose 6 teams. ***But*** the order of the teams does not matter, so we have to divide by the number of permutations of the teams ($6!$). This gives an end result of **190,590,400**, which appears to be the answer your book is expecting.

Basically, you are adding where you should be multiplying. See dmk's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/675581/15382) for a little more about that.

See if you can get started yourself on the second part. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Figured out B) as well with this reasoning. Guess I got to dug in on the problem I lost my bearings.

Comment: @Mylleranton Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

For (a), as an earlier comment stated, you're making order matter by using a permutation.  So, for example, you have $18$ choices for the first person on Team 1, $17$ choices for the second, and $16$ choices for the third.  Just as you wrote, this makes $18\cdot 17\cdot 16$ choices.  However, from those three people, we *could* have chosen the first person $3$ ways, the second $2$ ways, and the final person $1$ way. Therefore, $18\cdot 17\cdot 16$ overcounts the number of teams by a factor of $3\cdot 2 \cdot 1$. That means there are $\frac{18\cdot 17\cdot 16 }{3\cdot 2 \cdot 1}$ ways to choose the first team. This is equivalent to the binomial coefficient $\binom{18}{3}$, if you're familiar with combinations.

However, following this idea for each team will make your answer smaller, whereas your answer is too small to begin with.  What you want to do is *multiply* those fractions rather than add them.  Here we're determining one team *and then* determining another *and then* determining a third... Often, when an "and" appears as part of how you would complete a task (as above), that means you multiply.  An "or", on the other hand, tells you to add; for example, if you wanted to make only one team, and you wanted to know how many ways there were to create a team of either three or four people from 18, you'd calculate

$$\frac{18\cdot 17\cdot 16 }{3\cdot 2 \cdot 1} + \frac{18\cdot 17\cdot 16\cdot 15}{4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$$

Comment: This has some quite generally applicable reasoning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 for explaining the "and/or" thing, which I just sort of glossed over in my answer.